# Why STL <set> the overload operator < function must be a const function?

Tags: c++, stl, set, operator-overloading

```
class Test
{

public:

    int v;
    Test(int s)
    {
        v = s;
    }

    bool operator < (const Test & b) const
    {
        return v < b.v;
    }
};

int main()
{
    set <Test> t2;
    return 0;
}
```

Why must I use a const function when I overload the less operator? If i don't write the "const" there, it won't pass the compiling. So i don't know why MUST I write the "const" there?

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense to modify the object while comparing it.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that `std::set` is a bit special: the values it stores must not change (likewise the `key_type` in a `std::map`).  This is because `set` is a sorted container, and it needs to know how to sort the values; changing the values within the set could result in a broken program, because `set::set` has no way to know that the values have been changed and therefore would need to be sorted again.

If the comparison function were allowed to modify the values, then it could never be used, because the values in a set are always const.

As an aside, it is true that some modifications of the values are permissible, specifically modifications which do not affect the sort order.  So if you have a set with a custom sort function which sorts by one field of a struct, you can modify other fields of the struct because the sort order will remain the same.  But `std::set` has no way to understand which fields are important to the sort order and which are not, so the whole value is const.  You can do tricks like making some fields `mutable` to deal with this, but in most cases it is not necessary (e.g. you can use a map instead, and put the modifiable parts in the `value_type` instead).

Answer (score 1):

You are not required to do so. It's generally recommend because one shouldn't modify objects in the process of comparing them. `set<Test>` makes it a requirement by passing const references to `operator<`.

Comment: Some implementations barf if you don't do this.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Any implementation that doesn't permit a non-const `operator<` is broken. In the OP's case, the problem is with `set<Test>` trying to pass const references to `operator<`, not with `operator<` itself.

Comment: Do you have a C++ standard reference for that? Because it would mean gcc 4.8 and 4.9 are broken (and I'm sure I've seen this since 4.4.)

Comment: No I don't, but I just compiled a non-const operator< under   ideone's C++11 and C++ 4.8.1 compilers http://ideone.com/zgll93 http://ideone.com/etmMaz as well as g++ 4.8 and clang 6.0 on my laptop. In all cases, replacing `vector` with `set` causes the OP's problem.

Comment: The set is empty. Try inserting an element into it.

Comment: You two are both misunderstanding what the other is saying.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Yeah, I kinda got that impression after the last response.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I'm not saying that non-const `T::operator<` should work with `set<T>`, merely that nothing in the standard requires `operator<` to be non-const.

Comment: OK sorry, I hadn't seen the edit to your answer. It does make sense like this.